# All possible GOOS value?

Tags: go, cross-compiling

If I get it right, `GOOS` is determined when compile the source code.

To better support multiple OS, I'm interested in what `GOOS` could be.

Of course, there might be infinite possibilities of it, since Go is opensourced. So what I really want is a "common list".

Known values are:

- `windows`
- `linux`
- `darwin` or `freebsd` or `unix`? I know that at least one of them must exist.

Comment: You had selected the right answer before, and I detailed go tool dist list

Comment: @VonC Sure. Thanks for the update.

Comment: This page has a very comprehensible list of OS and architectures supported: https://go.dev/doc/install/source#environment

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Note that those values are defined in:

- [`src/go/build/syslist.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/build/syslist.go), and
- [`doc/install/source#environment`](https://go.dev/doc/install/source#environment).

With Go 1.5 (Q3 2015), `GOARCH` will become *much* more complete.
See [commit 1eebb91](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/1eebb91a5828c26532125b9464c92f721cd79d0f) by [Minux Ma (`minux`)](https://github.com/minux)

> ### `go/build`: reserve `GOARCH` values for *all* common architectures
>
> Whenever we introduce a new `GOARCH`, older Go releases won't recognize them and this causes trouble for both our users and us (we need to add unnecessary build tags).
>
> Go 1.5 has introduced three new GOARCHes so far: `arm64 ppc64 ppc64le`, we can take the time to introduce GOARCHes for all common architectures that Go might support in the future to avoid the problem.

```
const goosList = "android darwin dragonfly freebsd linux nacl \ 
  netbsd openbsd plan9 solaris windows "

const goarchList = "386 amd64 amd64p32 arm arm64 ppc64 ppc64le \
   mips mipsle mips64 mips64le mips64p32 mips64p32le \ # (new)
   ppc s390 s390x sparc sparc64 " # (new)
```

The list is still being review in [Change 9644](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/9644/), with comments like:

> I wouldn't bother with Itanium. It's basically a dead architecture.
> Plus, it's so hard to write a compiler for it that I really can't see it happening except as a labor of love, and nobody loves the Itanium.

The [**official documentation**](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment) now (GO 1.5+ Q3 2015) reflects that completed list.

---

Update 2018: as documented in [Giorgos Oikonomou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1199408/giorgos-oikonomou)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50117892/6309), Go 1.7 (Q1 2016) has introduced the
**`go tool dist list`** command.
See [commit c3ecded](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/c3ecded729214abf8a146902741cd6f9d257f68c): it fixes [issue 12270](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12270) opened in Q3 2015:

> To easier write tooling for cross compiling it would be good to programmatically get the possible combinations of GOOS and GOARCH.

This was implemented in [CL 19837](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/19837)

> `cmd/dist`: introduce `list` subcommand to list all supported platforms

You can list in plain text, or in json:

```
> go tool dist list -json
[
        {
                "GOOS": "android",
                "GOARCH": "386",
                "CgoSupported": true
        },
        ...
]
```

As [Mark Bates tweeted](https://twitter.com/markbates/status/1177326527287107585):

> Bonus: Column output properly formatted for display:
>
> ```
> go tool dist list | column -c 75 | column -t
> ```

Comment: This is very promising! And I'll accept this answer as correct when Go 1.5 is released.

Comment: I changed the selection of correct answer, because I think official document is better at this.

Comment: @liuyanghejerry the doc link? OK, I have added it to my answer. Is my answer ok now?

Comment: Yes, I've changed it back to yours. Thank you.

Answer (score 47):

I think you're looking for this list of possible GOOS and GOARCH combinations, in this section:

http://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment

> $GOOS and $GOARCH
>   The name of the target operating system and
>   compilation architecture. These default to the values of $GOHOSTOS and
>   $GOHOSTARCH respectively (described below).
>
> Choices for $GOOS are darwin (Mac OS X 10.8 and above and iOS),
>   dragonfly, freebsd, linux, netbsd, openbsd, plan9, solaris and
>   windows. Choices for $GOARCH are amd64 (64-bit x86, the most mature
>   port), 386 (32-bit x86), arm (32-bit ARM), arm64 (64-bit ARM), ppc64le
>   (PowerPC 64-bit, little-endian), ppc64 (PowerPC 64-bit, big-endian),
>   mips64le (MIPS 64-bit, little-endian), and mips64 (MIPS 64-bit,
>   big-endian). mipsle (MIPS 32-bit, little-endian), and mips (MIPS
>   32-bit, big-endian).
>
> The valid combinations of $GOOS and $GOARCH are:
>
> ```
> $GOOS $GOARCH
> android   arm
> darwin    386
> darwin    amd64
> darwin    arm
> darwin    arm64
> dragonfly amd64
> freebsd   386
> freebsd   amd64
> freebsd   arm
> linux     386
> linux     amd64
> linux     arm
> linux     arm64
> linux     ppc64
> linux     ppc64le
> linux     mips
> linux     mipsle
> linux     mips64
> linux     mips64le
> netbsd    386
> netbsd    amd64
> netbsd    arm
> openbsd   386
> openbsd   amd64
> openbsd   arm
> plan9     386
> plan9     amd64
> solaris   amd64
> windows   386
> windows   amd64
> ```

Answer (score 32):

You can see the list of supported platform by running:

`go tool dist list`

and  this will print(depending on the Go version):

```
android/386
android/amd64
android/arm
android/arm64
darwin/386
darwin/amd64
darwin/arm
darwin/arm64
dragonfly/amd64
freebsd/386
freebsd/amd64
freebsd/arm
linux/386
linux/amd64
linux/arm
linux/arm64
linux/mips
linux/mips64
linux/mips64le
linux/mipsle
linux/ppc64
linux/ppc64le
linux/s390x
nacl/386
nacl/amd64p32
nacl/arm
netbsd/386
netbsd/amd64
netbsd/arm
openbsd/386
openbsd/amd64
openbsd/arm
plan9/386
plan9/amd64
plan9/arm
solaris/amd64
windows/386
windows/amd64
```

And the official documentation for the tool:

https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/go/src/cmd/dist

To cross compile use:

```
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=386 go build main.go
```

Comment: I think it's a pretty new method along with some new version of Go? Do you have official document for it?