# Errors setting up Go for cross-compiling

Tags: linux, go, cross-compiling, archlinux

I'm using Linux 64-bit and I'm trying to set up Go for cross-compiling (for Windows, specifically). There's an awesome guide for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168873/cross-compile-go-on-osx). But when I try to run the second command below:

```
cd /usr/lib/go/src
sudo GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 CGO_ENABLED=0 ./make.bash --no-clean
```

I get errors when it tries to build the `cmd` package. It says `use of internal package not allowed`. Is this a bug in Go's main source code? I'll paste the full list of errors.

```
# Building packages and commands for host, linux/amd64.
package cmd/cmd/pprof
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/driver: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/fetch: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/symbolizer: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/symbolz: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/commands
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/report: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/commands
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/svg: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/commands
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/tempfile: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/driver
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/commands: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/driver
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/report: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/driver
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/tempfile: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/fetch
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/plugin: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/fetch
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/profile: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/plugin
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/profile: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/report
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/plugin: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/report
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/profile: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/symbolizer
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/plugin: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/symbolizer
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/profile: use of internal package not allowed
package cmd/cmd/pprof/internal/symbolz
    imports cmd/pprof/internal/profile: use of internal package not allowed
```

I can't find anything like this on Google, so that probably means I'm doing something wrong. I'm using Arch Linux, by the way, and I installed `Go` with `pacman`, not from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error comes from [`cmd/go/pkg.go#L358`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/9af454c588ee0bef7fc6ae588e2b2e866edcb915/src/cmd/go/pkg.go#L352), and a look at the blame view show this has been introduced by [commit 1338f32](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/1338f327b2deb81ba81107b5033d1b10e97e3abe) for go 1.4

So the guide might work only with go 1.3-, not go 1.4, because of the [Go 1.4 "Internal" Package proposition](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e8kOo3r51b2BWtTs_1uADIA5djfXhPT36s6eHVRIvaU/edit).

> For Go 1.4, we will implement the rule first for `$GOROOT`, but not `$GOPATH`. We will use the compiler conversion and some minor uses in the standard library to gain experience with the rule.
>
> Due to an irregularity in the main repo, as a special case, the “`/pkg/`” element in `$GOROOT/src/pkg/…` paths is considered not to exist.
> This means that `$GOROOT/src/pkg/internal` can be imported by `$GOROOT/src/cmd/…` in addition to `$GOROOT/src/pkg/…`.
> This special case will be removed when we move the standard library up to `$GOROOT/src/`.

Comment: So is it not possible to setup cross-compilation on Arch Linux with Go 1.4? Or is there some workaround?

Comment: @m01 not that I know of. Go 1.5 will make cross-compilation dead-simple though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28829037/6309, and https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GoTalks#go-in-go, like https://talks.golang.org/2015/gogo.slide#18, using goos and goarch presented in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30068222/6309.

Comment: Ok - sounds like my options are: go back to Go 1.3, go forward to the dev version of Go 1.5, or wait for Go 1.5 to be released. Thanks!

Comment: @m01 I agree. Go 1.5 will be released in August, so in 2 months or so.

Comment: Since I've run in to this many times, I thought I'd add my workaround for using 1.4: Move `$GOROOT/src/cmd/cmd/pprof` to `$GOPATH/src/cmd/cmd/pprof` and everything should compile fine.